boundary term in the integration by parts of difference quotients
This question is related to my other question boundary term in the integration by parts formula for difference quotient.
Now, let us consider two functions $f,g\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and a time interval $(0,T)$. Let us consider the integration by parts of difference quotients:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}g(x)dx=-\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}dx.
\end{align}
But since these two are differentable functions, so the difference quotients should converge to the derivative. Hence, passing to the limit implies
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}f^{\prime}(x)g(x)dx=-\int_{0}^{T}f(x)g^{\prime}(x)dx.
\end{align}
I do not think this is usually true, because the boundary terms are missing. So I really wonder where does the mistake occur?

I think that your integration by parts formula is wrong, the  formula holds when one of the functions has compact support in the domain of integration, and in this case both f and g don't need to have compact support in (0, T). In fact if you do the change of variable you'll have trouble with the interval of integration because neither f nor g has compact support

anyway if you assume that either f or g has compact support in (0,T) then the identity you want to conclude is indeed true, since by integration by parts the boundary terms vanishes

The integration by parts for the difference quotients is wrong: the term involving $g(x+h)$ should read $\int_{-h}^{T-h} f(x) g(x+h)$.
The correct formula is
$$
\int_0^T \frac1h( f(x)-f(x-h))g(x) dx 
= \int_0^T \frac1h  f(x)g(x) dx -\int_{-h}^{T-h} \frac1h f(x)g(x+h) dx \\
= \int_0^T \frac1h  f(x)(g(x)-g(x+h)) dx  -  \frac1h\int_{-h}^0 f(x)g(x+h) dx
+ \frac1h\int_{T-h}^T  f(x)g(x+h) dx.
$$
So you get two boundary contributions, which converge to the boundary terms in the integration-by-parts formula for $h\searrow0$.
